# Delete every row of data preceding "MSG" row in txt file?

Tags: python, csv, awk

I have a txt file that has 70K or so rows of data with 8 or so columns. The 2nd column defines the data type (either SMP or MSG). Within that data file, there are 62 rows of data total identified as "MSG". I am trying to make a simple awk command or even a short python script that will delete 1 row of data that precedes every "MSG" row in the file. Example section out of actual data file:

```
976810  SMP  2  144.79  108.25  
993461  SMP  2  144.68  108.15
945277  SMP  2  144.90  108.10
945828  SMP  3  144.83  108.31      
945237  MSG  3  # Message: 5
943544  SMP  3  144.87  108.58      
945209  SMP  3  144.93  108.68
976916  SMP  3  145.17  108.72
997481  SMP  3  140.90  109.33  
914197  SMP  4  140.79  109.15  
945300  MSG  4  # Message: 0
940848  SMP  4  140.84  109.11
945568  SMP  4  140.91  109.03  
945200  SMP  4  141.08  109.01
```

So in the example above, I need to delete the SMP lines right before every MSG line.
I thought maybe I'd use an awk command to search for $2=='MSG' and then delete row MSG-1 or something. 
I very much appreciate any suggestions/help/guidance on this!

Regards

Comment: Using the above example, can you add that again but show what the output should look like?  That will make sure people understand your question :)

Comment: What do you expect to happen if there are consecutive "MSG" lines?

Comment: Hello!

There are most definitely no consecutive MSG lines. There are always at least 240 lines of SMP data between each MSG line. The reason I need to delete 1 row before every MSG line is because the numbering has a slight delay to it when the data gets received (as you can tell above, the number beside SMP should increment at every MSG, but alas the data lag many times increments the trial # right before MSG even pops up)

Comment: And Trevor, this is what the output would be: 

976810  SMP  2  144.79  108.25  
993461  SMP  2  144.68  108.15
945277  SMP  2  144.90  108.10
945828  SMP  3  144.83  108.31(This entire line would be deleted)      
945237  MSG  3  # Message: 5
943544  SMP  3  144.87  108.58      
945209  SMP  3  144.93  108.68
976916  SMP  3  145.17  108.72
997481  SMP  3  140.90  109.33  
914197  SMP  4  140.79  109.15(This entire line would be deleted)  
945300  MSG  4  # Message: 0
940848  SMP  4  140.84  109.11
945568  SMP  4  140.91  109.03  
945200  SMP  4  141.08  109.01

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk 'NR>1 && $2!="MSG"{print prev} {prev=$0} END{print prev}' file
976810  SMP  2  144.79  108.25
993461  SMP  2  144.68  108.15
945277  SMP  2  144.90  108.10
945237  MSG  3  # Message: 5
943544  SMP  3  144.87  108.58
945209  SMP  3  144.93  108.68
976916  SMP  3  145.17  108.72
997481  SMP  3  140.90  109.33
945300  MSG  4  # Message: 0
940848  SMP  4  140.84  109.11
945568  SMP  4  140.91  109.03
945200  SMP  4  141.08  109.01
```

Comment: Ed Morton,

Thank you for the help! This is perfect. My initial awk command was unfortunately a few characters different from what you've posted, and of course figuring out what was wrong was taking longer than it needed to. Much obliged. 
For anyone else/new coders, to ensure the awk command's output is saved into a new file:
more yourTextFile.txt | awk 'NR>1 && $2!="MSG"{print prev} {prev=$0} END{print prev}' > newTextFile.txt

Comment: Youre welcome. wrt that last sentence in your comment - using `more` to pipe the file to awk is useless (same as UUOC - google it) and the output redirection is basic shell , unrelated to awk or any other specific command and doesn't need to be said in this context.

Comment: Thanks Ed. Sure, it's basic shell, but I figure more info is better than none for future Googlers with similar issues. Plus ^the pipeline tied up what I needed out of this question, with your help.